# How do US professors consider about Chinese undergraduate candidates’ application for theoretical physics?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, application

I heard they like students from their own university, and there is little chance that students from other colleges can be part of their research. Is that true?

Comment: If two candidates look equal on paper, but you have met in person with one, or s/he attended your courses, you have evidence about whether the candidate meets their "on paper" description. Someone you have not interacted with is always a question mark. Also, it is difficult for a Western academic to judge Chinese and Indian undergraduate CVs (once the candidate has publications it becomes much easier). This is due in part to the large number of universities with wildly varying quality standards, and also to the large number of spam applications received (especially from India and Pakistan).

Answer (score -2):

The best way to answer this question is with data.  Most US universities are very open.

1. Assemble a list of US theoretical physics departments.
2. Scrape their respective web pages for information about their current post-graduate and alumni post-graduate students - specifically look for their undergraduate degrees.  I think this information is publicly available but not in a convenient format.
3. Can you find out information about all applicants? I don't know if this information is publicly available, but if it is you will definitely have to work on it.  You might need to email some universities and push them.
4. Perform statistical analysis.
5. Summarize your findings and submit to an appropriate journal.
6. Congratulations you have a publication credit which will strengthen your application.  The analysis will also help you known which departments are most open to Chinese undergraduate students.

Good Luck!

Comment: "Research by yourself and publish the results" may answer any question in StackExchange. However, I doubt that it meets the OP's needs or any future reader's needs in any question.